# Horizontal Stripes in my Laptop screen

Tags: 14.04

I am using Dell Inspiron 14 4050 with ubuntu 14.04.3. 5 days before I was downloading pdfs in firefox and watching movie in vlc while charging the laptop. Then my laptop screen changed green and black horizontal stripes. so I shutdown my laptop manually, after 30 mins I restarted my laptop, first in boot screen the stripes was in my screen when ubuntu logo came there is no stripes. so I started downloading. Then the stripes came just in  bottom of the screen so I powered off my laptpo. then I powered on again my laptop there is no colour in my screen no Dell logo on boot no ubuntu logo, but everything else is working fine. Today I powered on my laptop the screen was normal, after 15 mins the whole screen changed to pink and black horizontal stripes and no colour after restarting. what do i do now?

I connected a monitor using VGA cable while there is no colour in laptop screen, but monitor worked fine.